# What is the best way to be notified of changes in an QAbstractItemView

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel

I have a QListView that has its model (derived from QAbstractItemModel) regularly changed based on a some criteria in the UI. I would like to be notified when the view itself believes a new row has been added/removed either when the current model updates or when the model is changed. I need this notification so that I can call setIndexWidget and add a custom control under a particular column. I would prefer not to call setIndexWidget repeatedly because the population of the widget is expensive. So once per row would be ideal.

I've tried rowsInserted/rowsAboutToBeRemoved and dataChanged but those don't get called if the model being set into the view already has items in it.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that when you are filling the model that you are not replacing it (with a different QAbstractItemModel object) causing your initial connections to the QListView to be lost?

Comment: isn't setModel supposed to handle all of those connections?

Comment: SetModel will handle that correctly if you connect to the signals for the QListView. I was trying to figure out a cause for the problem and I thought your were directly connecting to the signals for your model then changing the model. In that case your signals to no longer be sent unless you updated your connections after changing the model.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong about `dataChanged`. If the contents of any data item change, then `dataChanged` is signaled. The following invariant holds, assuming that the `dataChanged` slot is connected to the same signal on the model.

```
class ... : public QObject {
  QModelIndex m_index;
  bool m_changed;
  Q_SLOT void dataChanged(const QModelIndex & tl) {
    m_changed = m_changed || tl == m_index;
  }
  ...
};  

m_index = QModelIndex(...);
QVariant before, after;
m_changed = false;
before = model->data(index);
after = model->data(index);
Q_ASSERT(before == after || m_changed);
```

What you're describing is most likely caused by incorrect behavior of your model. There is a model test suite you could use to verify compliance of your model with required invariants.

Addressing your question points specifically:

1. I would like to be notified when the view itself believes a new row has been added/removed either when the current model updates...

   The view doesn't need to believe anything. Your model must be emitting relevant signals to that effect. Simply connect to those signals from some `QObject`. That's all the view is doing. If the signals don't fire, the view won't be notified. End of story.
2. ... or when the model is changed.

   There's no signal for that since the entire model is replaced. You're the one who calls `setModel` on the view, so that shouldn't be a problem. You better know when the call is made :)

Comment: But my model does not change. Why would dataChanged get called if I just assign a static model to a view? I mean, that's the behavior I want but that doesn't seem to be how it works.

Comment: You say that the model gets changed. Are you literally swapping the entire model?

Comment: I occasionally swap the model with another calling setModel. But those models that are set into the view have the potential to change while set in the view and while not set in the view. They also have the potential to not change at all.